# Apache flume build failure due to connection time out error

Tags: apache, maven

I have installing the Apache Flume 1.5.1 on the windows with help of the guide given [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLUME/Build+Flume+1.3.x+up+on+Windows) . then i faced one issue in stage of building the flume source. issue details below

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.1:process (default) on project flume-ng-morphline-solr-sink: Failed to resolve dependencies for one or more projects in the reactor. Reason: Missing:
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:1.0.1
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.flume.flume-ng-sinks:flume-ng-morphline-solr-sink:jar:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 2) com.cloudera.cdk:cdk-morphlines-all:pom:0.6.0
[ERROR] 3) com.cloudera.cdk:cdk-morphlines-solr-core:jar:0.6.0
[ERROR] 4) org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:4.4.0
[ERROR] 5) org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:1.0.1
```

and resolved this by commands `mvn -Dhadoop.profile=2 clean test -DskipTests` source https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-2184

there after also i am not get succeed . getting the below connection time out error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project flume-ng-morphline-solr-sink: Could no
t resolve dependencies for project org.apache.flume.flume-ng-sinks:flume-ng-morp
hline-solr-sink:jar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact ua_parser:ua-par
ser:jar:1.3.0 from/to maven-twttr (maven.twttr.com): Connect to maven.twt
tr.com:80 [maven.twttr.com/199.59.148.212] failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

i have followed below link to solve this issue but not succeed at all .

blog.csdn.net/yydcj/article/details/38824823

www.iteblog.com/archives/1043

please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is arise due to network problem that is in my organisation sonicwall has blocked this connection so i am getting this issue.